# Linked vector files in a photoshop file for sharing with co-worker

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a multi-layered Photoshop document with multiple linked file icons which I need to make accessible for a colleague to work on another machine. Does anyone know of a quick way that the co-worker can link to the images? Or is the only solution to embed all images?

Answer (score 1):

If your co-worker needs to work with the icons and the icons are linked then you either need to send the Photoshop file with the linked icons files or embedded the icons.